# Angular: How to filter json with specific keys

Tags: angularjs, aem, aem-6

I am getting a json from multiselect items which are checked.  How do I filter json based on specific keys only from the below original json:

Original Json:

```
 {
        "Reward": [{
            "RewardType": 1,
            "RewardTypeValue": "PartCodes",
            "RewardCode": "CB_USD_20_US",
            "DiscountValue": 20.0
        },
        {
            "RewardType": 1,
            "RewardTypeValue": "PartCodes",
            "RewardCode": "CB_USD_30_US",
            "DiscountValue": 30.0
        },
        {
            "RewardType": 1,
            "RewardTypeValue": "PartCodes",
            "RewardCode": "CB_USD_40_US",
            "DiscountValue": 40.0
        },
        {
            "RewardType": 1,
            "RewardTypeValue": "PartCodes",
            "RewardCode": "CB_USD_50_US",
            "DiscountValue": 50.0
        }]

    }
```

At this below code, I am trying to get only RewardType,RewardCode and DiscountType before calling "push" for "selectedRewards"

Angular Code:

```
  $scope.rewards = [];
$scope.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection(selectedRewards) {
   var idx = $scope.rewards.indexOf(selectedRewards);
   console.log(selectedRewards);

   // is currently selected
   if (idx > -1) {
     $scope.rewards.splice(idx, 1);
   }

   // is newly selected
   else {

     $scope.rewards.push(selectedRewards);
   }
   console.log($scope.rewards);
};
```

Html code:

```
<li ng-repeat="reward in RewardsList ">
           <input id="{{reward.RewardCode}}.{{reward.RewardType}}"
                  type="checkbox"
                  ng-checked="selection.indexOf(reward.RewardCode) > -1"
                  ng-click="toggleSelection(reward)"
                  value="{{reward.RewardCode}}" /> 
    <label  for="{{reward.RewardCode}}">{{reward.RewardCode}}</label>
    </li>
```

here is the expected json I am trying to get:

```
{
        "Reward": [{
            "RewardType": 1,
            "RewardCode": "CB_USD_20_US",
            "DiscountValue": 20.0
        },
        {
            "RewardType": 1,
            "RewardCode": "CB_USD_30_US",
            "DiscountValue": 30.0
        },
        {
            "RewardType": 1,
            "RewardCode": "CB_USD_40_US",
            "DiscountValue": 40.0
        },
        {
            "RewardType": 1,
            "RewardCode": "CB_USD_50_US",
            "DiscountValue": 50.0
        }]

    }
```

Comment: Not enough known or shown. We have no idea where `selectedRewards` comes from or what expected results are. Please provide a more detailed explanation and a [mcve]

Comment: expected result is json minus the  "RewardTypeValue" key/value.

Comment: Sorry...be more specific with expected results

Comment: expected json added.

Comment: just loop over it and use `delete` on that property. If only want to delete on a copy use `angular.copy()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following fixed my issue:

**Code:**

```
$scope.rewards.push({"RewardType":selectedRewards.RewardType, "RewardCode":selectedRewards.RewardCode," "DiscountValue":selectedRewards.DiscountValue});
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't really get what is the variable which stores the json in your code, but let's say your variable is called `myJson` and corresponds to the original json you've shared. To get the expected json you'd do:

```
var expectedJson = {
  Reward: myJson.Reward.map(function(item) {
    return {
     RewardType: item.RewardType,
     RewardCode: item.RewardCode,
     DiscountValue: item.DiscountValue
    }
  })
}
```

Have a look at `Array.prototype.map` if you're not familiar with it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: getting the message clientlibs.min.js:formatted:3289 TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. I am using angular 1.4

Comment: answering your 1st question: selectedRewards will receive the original json. It is a dynamic call so array json size is not defined.

Comment: so you call the few lines of code I wrote just after your `selectedRewards` variable is filled (I'd say juste before to push)